# Is there a way to set marginLeft dynamically?

Tags: highcharts

I built a stacked bar chart with drilldown

http://jsfiddle.net/uemit/9CJHq/1/

and I configured the chart to have "marginLeft: 90". But I'd like "marginLeft" to be "40" when the drilldown happens. Is there a way to set marginLeft dynamically?

```
    function setChart(name, categories, data) {
        chart.counters.color = 0;
        chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories);
        while (chart.series.length > 0) {
            chart.series[0].remove(true);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            chart.addSeries({
                name: name[i],
                data: data[i]
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can't you just remove that `marginLeft` from options to allow Highcharts set dynamic margin?

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was just too easy. Why did I start using "marginLeft" in the first place?